# I have an old hand built power supply, am I missing something?

Tags: power-supply

My father-in-law and mentor passed away during COVID, in 2020. I am now just cleaning out his shop. Just couldn't do it. My friend (who also considered him a mentor) are splitting his supplies, throwing out obvious garbage (because there is a LOT!). We plan to sell off some because we will never use it all.

I got one of his functioning scopes, and a few other items including his homemade bench supply (we actually found two very similar). It is based on a variable transformer that feeds another transformer (isolation I believe) then rectifies it with a homemade bridge and some large value older caps. Its very home brew and had a few repairs over the years.

The main problem is that it is not enclosed. Where he had it this was not an issue for him but I plan to enclose it.

Before I go messing about I am trying to draw a schematic because he did this many years ago and I can't find a record. I probably will replace the caps too if need be. During this process I may clean it up a bit...don't know. I do know I need to add a better plug, IEC is the plan.

I am pretty new to electronics and recognize most things but I am having issues on why certain things are the way they are.

1. I am still trying to get values on the current, I believe its less than 5 A (that is the panel fuse). Am I correct that the variable transformer is driving the primary?
2. The secondary has two red taps and one white one between them. I think that means this transformer is a center tap does that seem accurate?
3. any tips or errors that seem blatant. I am new to schematic drawing and tried to replicate the device as best I could just mapping the connections. It is all wire to wire, no PCB at all.

[image: Power supply schematic]

HERE IS THE EDIT
[image: ROUND 2 EDIT]

Comment: I wanna say your diodes or your capacitors are drawn backwards.

Comment: your schematic is somewhat convoluted ... if you closely examine the four polarized capacitors, you'll discover that the top one is parallel with the bottom one ... and the two in the middle are also parallel

Comment: What are the values and voltage ratings of each capacitor? Does the rectifier have a part number on it?

Comment: I agree that the diodes are drawn backwards. If that is a 24V center tapped transformer, the output will be about +18 / 0 /-18 VDC (open circuit peak), and about +12 / 0 / -12 VDC under load. The voltmeter reads the full 36 or 24 VDC.

Comment: You should add a fuse on the left before the switch. Switch the hot line, not the neutral. If you put it in a metal box, connect the box to the ground pin of the plug.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I defiantly think it was convoluted. It was late and I was just trying to write out what I saw. You are correct lots of things were and still are a bit nutty on my "schematic". Corrected a bit of the schematic. I definitely agree about the earthing and fusing the thing a bit better when i am done. I was surprised but this thing he ran open on a bench shelf so he probably was ok with it. I want to keep it for his sake but clean it up and maybe re cap the thing, I will have to get values for part. The bridge is homemade out of large rectifier diodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to thank everyone for the helpful comments. Most of this was me trying to debug this in air construction. I am posting my final schematic which now makes sense to me. Sorry for the late reply but its been a rough year. Thank you! I am not 100% on the values but I have enough to move forward putting this in a proper case. It will work but it will never be my only supply, I just wanted to make sure it worked and make it a bit safer to use. I will try to post pics of the final product.[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I am still trying to get values on the current, I believe its less
> than 5 A (that is the panel fuse). Am I correct that the variable
> transformer is driving the primary?

The only way to work out the maximum current rating is to identify the components, and then find their maximum current rating.  The transformer or the diodes are likely to be the limiting factors.

The variable transformer (variac) will be driving the primary.  It's a novel way to turn a fixed voltage power supply into a variable one.

> The secondary has two red taps and one white one between them. I think
> that means this transformer is a center tap does that seem accurate?

Given the circuit diagram, that makes sense.  The center tap gives a 0V line between the +V and -V outputs.

> Any tips or errors that seem blatant. I am new to schematic drawing
> and tried to replicate the device as best I could just mapping the
> connections. It is all wire to wire, no PCB at all.

As others have pointed out in the comments, the diodes are drawn the wrong way round, when compared with the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

This schematic may be easier to comprehend.

[image]